# Dart: Class members seem to be wrong when access from a separate class

Tags: dart

Anyone know if this is a Dart bug or is it my misunderstanding of how Dart coding works?

I am learning Dart to investigate feasibility of eventually using Flutter; however, while exploring the language, I found a weird behavior (maybe a bug).  I tried repro'ing it by writing a similar pattern of code, but have yet to figure out what causes it.  In the attached code, I wrote a quicksort class.  In that class, it counts the number of times the "sort" method is recursed and saves the count in a class member called "recurseCount".

From the main() class, if I use the QuickSort class directly, I have no issue getting back the recurseCount member; however, if I call it from a different class (called "Tester"), I do not get the correct value for "recurseCount".  Why would calling a class from a separate class cause members to not provide the correct values?

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'dart:math' as _math;

// ***********************
enum SortOrder { ascending, descending, unsorted }

class QuickSort {
  List list = [];
  SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.unsorted;
  int recurseCount = 0;

  QuickSort({this.list}) {
    if (list != null && list.length > 1) {
      list = sort(useRandomPivot: true);
    }
  }

  List sort(
      {List iList,
      int leftIndex = 0,
      int rightIndex,
      bool useRandomPivot = true}) {
    if (iList != null) list = iList;
    if (list.isEmpty) return [];
    rightIndex ??= list.length - 1;
    if (rightIndex > list.length - 1) rightIndex = list.length - 1;

    if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
      recurseCount++;
      var partitionIndex =
          _partition(leftIndex, rightIndex, useRandomPivot: useRandomPivot);
      if (partitionIndex == -1) {
        //already sorted List
        if (sortOrder == SortOrder.ascending) {
          return list;
        } else {
          //SortOrder.descending
          list = list.reversed.toList(); // Time Complexity of O(n)
          sortOrder = SortOrder.ascending;
          return list;
        }
      } else {
        sort(leftIndex: leftIndex, rightIndex: partitionIndex - 1);
        sort(leftIndex: partitionIndex + 1, rightIndex: rightIndex);
      }
    } else {
      sortOrder = SortOrder.ascending;
    }
    return list;
  }

  int _partition(int leftIndex, int rightIndex, {bool useRandomPivot = true}) {
    // in case the array is already sorted from the start; only run through the partition'ing one time
    //  note: regardless of ascending or descending order
    if (leftIndex == 0 && rightIndex >= list.length - 1) {
      sortOrder = checkSorting(list);
      if (sortOrder != SortOrder.unsorted) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (useRandomPivot) {
        var random = _math.Random();
        var randomIndex = random.nextInt(rightIndex - leftIndex);
        _swapElements(randomIndex, rightIndex);
      }
    }

    int pivotVal = list[rightIndex]; //select the last item as the pivot

    var headIndex = leftIndex - 1;

    for (var scanIndex = leftIndex; scanIndex < rightIndex; scanIndex++) {
      if (list[scanIndex] <= pivotVal) {
        headIndex++;
        _swapElements(headIndex, scanIndex);
      }
    }

    var partitionIndex = headIndex + 1;
    _swapElements(partitionIndex, rightIndex);
    return partitionIndex;
  }

  void _swapElements(position1, position2) {
    int tempVal = list[position1];
    list[position1] = list[position2];
    list[position2] = tempVal;
  }

  SortOrder checkSorting(List arr) {
    var isAsc = true;
    var isDesc = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) isDesc = false;
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) isAsc = false;
      if (!isDesc && !isAsc) break; // not sorted Asc or Desc
    }
    if (isAsc) {
      return SortOrder.ascending;
    } else if (isDesc) return SortOrder.descending;
    return SortOrder.unsorted;
  }
}

// ***********************TESTS*********************************
num log2(num n) => _math.log(n) / _math.ln2;

List getRandomIntList({int min = 0, int max = 10000, int len}) {
  var random = _math.Random();
  var tempList = List(len);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tempList[i] = random.nextInt(max - min);
  }
  return tempList;
}

class Tester {
  static num _runControlTest(List list) {
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.start();
    list.sort();
    stopwatch.stop();
    return stopwatch.elapsedMicroseconds;
  }

  static void runTests(List list, String groupName,
      {bool useRandomPivot = false, bool sortFromConstructor = false}) {
    // CONTROL
    var controlElapsedTimeMicroSec = 0;
    controlElapsedTimeMicroSec = _runControlTest(list);
    // END CONTROL

    var expectedRecursionCountLogN = log2(list.length).ceil();
    var expectedRecursionCountNLogN = list.length * expectedRecursionCountLogN;

    var qs = QuickSort();
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.start();
    list =
        qs.sort(iList: list, useRandomPivot: useRandomPivot); // METHOD TO TEST
    stopwatch.stop();

    var elapsedTimeMicroSec = stopwatch.elapsedMicroseconds;
    var recursionCount = qs
        .recurseCount; //NOTE (BUG in Dart?): unable to get the recurseCount correctly from within this class/method

    group(groupName, () {
      var testSubject =
          'Time Taken: ${controlElapsedTimeMicroSec} microseconds';
      var reason =
          'The built in sort took ${controlElapsedTimeMicroSec} microseconds, while the test took ${elapsedTimeMicroSec}.';
      test(testSubject, () {
        expect(
            elapsedTimeMicroSec, lessThanOrEqualTo(controlElapsedTimeMicroSec),
            reason: reason);
      });

      testSubject =
          'Time Complexity: ${recursionCount} vs ${expectedRecursionCountNLogN}';
      reason =
          'Time Complexity of ${recursionCount} is greater than either range (LogN) ${expectedRecursionCountLogN} or (N*LogN) ${expectedRecursionCountNLogN}';

      test(testSubject, () {
        expect(recursionCount, lessThanOrEqualTo(expectedRecursionCountNLogN),
            reason: reason);
      });
    });
  }
}

void main() {
  var min = 0;
  var len = 1000000;
  var max = len;

  var originalList = getRandomIntList(min: min, max: max, len: len);
  var list = List.from(originalList);
  // BUG? When called within this Tester.runTests the sort method does NOT return the correct recurseCount
  Tester.runTests(list, 'UNSORTED_RIGHT_PIVOT', useRandomPivot: false);

  list = List.from(originalList);
  var qs = QuickSort();
  // When called directly from main() the sort method DOES return the correct recurseCount
  var stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  qs.sort(iList: list, useRandomPivot: true); //METHOD TO TEST
  stopwatch.stop();
  group('UNSORTED_RANDOM_PIVOT', () {
    test('Time Taken: ${stopwatch.elapsedMicroseconds} microseconds', () {
      expect(stopwatch.elapsedMicroseconds,
          lessThanOrEqualTo(Tester._runControlTest(originalList)));
    });
    var nLogN = (list.length * (log2(list.length).ceil()));
    test('Time Complexity: ${qs.recurseCount} vs $nLogN', () {
      expect(qs.recurseCount, lessThanOrEqualTo(nLogN));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `runTests` function calls `_runControlTest(list)` which sorts `list` by mutation.  When `runTests` later runs your `QuickSort.sort` implementation, it never needs to recurse because `list` is already sorted.  In contrast, your second approach runs `_runControlTest` on a separate list.

Comment: OMG...Thank you so much.  I was going cross-eyed and didn't even notice that.

Comment: I modified the runTests(..) to have this instead and everything works now.
```
    var controlList = List.from(list);
    var controlElapsedTimeMicroSec = 0;
    controlElapsedTimeMicroSec = _runControlTest(controlList);
```